# Biztalk Server's Number of Concurrent Orchestrations Is Too Few

Tags: biztalk

We're currently having an issue with our Biztalk having too few concurrent orchestrations and is causing delay in delivering messages. The system has been running for years and the issue happened just recently. In a normal state it would have 20-40 concurrent orchestrations but currently it's been running only 4 or less at the same time.

The same configuration on a test server is working properly so at first we thought clearing the database would help, but unfortunately hasn't.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were there any new applications added or any recent changes? Even windows updates or installation of CU for either BizTalk or Adapter Packs?

Comment: The only changes were Windows updates.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to fire up Performance Monitor and see if the system is Throttling and if so, why.  See: [Host Throttling Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx)